# Flask-Login with Multiple User Classes

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So In my flask project I've used Flask-Login to implement a login/registration system. However that is for my Users table. I also have a "Booster" table which has almost the same properties, but a little more. For example, the booster will login to a different part of the website. I have it separated by the routes. So my routes I have are /login, /register and /booster_login and /booster_register. I tried to use the login_user method on my login method under booster_login, but I'm getting a object has no is_active attribute when I submit the booster_login form. I can not just use roles since boosters will have many more attributes than users.

My models.py is here

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin import Admin    
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room
import datetime

db = SQLAlchemy()
socketio = SocketIO()

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    role = db.Column(db.String(80))

class Booster(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    booster_name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    join_date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True))
    current_order = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('orders.id'))
    current_balance = db.Column(db.Float)

    def __init__(self, booster_name, email, password, join_date):
        self.booster_name = booster_name
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
        self.join_date = join_date
```

https://github.com/bshelton/flask-boost/blob/master/views.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, Blueprint, request

from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user   
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, functools
from sqlalchemy import func
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
#from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from .boostforms import LoginForm, RegisterForm, SoloOrderForm

from .models import User, db, socketio, ChatLog, Orders, join_room, Booster

import datetime

mainbp = Blueprint('mainbp', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static') 

users = {}

@mainbp.route('/')

def index():   
    return render_template('index.html')

@mainbp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])  
def login():  
    form = LoginForm() 
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        submitted_username = form.username.data

        submitted_username = str(submitted_username)

        submitted_username = submitted_username.lower() 

        user = User.query.filter(func.lower(User.username)==submitted_username).first()

        print (user)   
        if user:

            if user.username.lower() == submitted_username.lower():

                if sha256_crypt.verify(form.password.data, user.password) and user.role == "Admin":

                    login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)

                    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('.admindashboard'))

                elif sha256_crypt.verify(form.password.data, user.password) and user.role == "Client":

                    login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)

                    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('.userdashboard'))

                else: 
                     return '<h1> You\'re stupid </h1>' 
            else:  
                return '<h1> Invalid Login </h1>'  
        else:
            return '<h1> Invalid Login </h1>'

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@mainbp.route('/boosterlogin', methods=["GET", "POST"])   
def boosterlogin():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        submitted_username = form.username.data

        submitted_username = str(submitted_username)

        submitted_username = submitted_username.lower()

        booster = Booster.query.filter(func.lower(Booster.booster_name)==submitted_username).first()

        print (booster.booster_name)

        if booster:

            print (booster.password)

            print (form.password.data)

            if booster.booster_name.lower() == submitted_username.lower():

                if sha256_crypt.verify(form.password.data, booster.password):

                    login_user(booster, remember=form.remember.data)

                    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('.index'))

                else:

                     return '<h1> Wrong Password </h1>'

            else:
                return '<h1> Invalid Login </h1>'

        else:

            return '<h1> Invalid Login </h1>'



    return render_template('boosterlogin.html', form=form)


@mainbp.route('/logout')
@login_required 
def logout():
    logout_user()

    return redirect(url_for('.index'))
@mainbp.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        hash_password = sha256_crypt.hash(form.password.data)

        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hash_password)

        db.session.add(new_user)

        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('.login'))

    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

@mainbp.route('/booster_register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def booster_register():

    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        booster_name = form.username.data

        hash_password = sha256_crypt.hash(form.password.data)

        email = form.email.data

        join_date = datetime.datetime.now()

        print ("booster_name: " + booster_name + " password: " + hash_password + " email: " + email)

        new_booster = Booster(booster_name=booster_name, email=email, password=hash_password, join_date=datetime.datetime.now())

        db.session.add(new_booster)

        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('.boosterlogin'))

    return render_template('booster_register.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Maybe this is edited for brevity but you really shouldn't store `password =` in plaintext in your DB. It is a serious security concern as well as opening yourself to litigation in case of breach.

Comment: password isn't stored in clear text. password is the field name nad hash_password is the sha256 hash...

Answer (score 0):

When you are using flask-login `login()` method, It will expect a `UserMixin` object which implements these missing attributes.
In your code you are only implementing UserMixin in your User model. Try to have Booster inherit from your `User` class like the below.

```
class Booster(User):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    booster_name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    join_date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True))
    current_order = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('orders.id'))
    current_balance = db.Column(db.Float)

    def __init__(self, booster_name, email, password, join_date):
        self.booster_name = booster_name
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
        self.join_date = join_date
```